# Auto Increment of JAR file version in the Azure DevOPS pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have a task to increase the JAR version automatically in Azure DevOPS, once the changes are made to the particular branch.
SCM used here is Bit Bucket. Repository storage is Azure DevOPS Artifact section.

I need to pick the version from the artifact section in Azure DevOPS and increment in the azure pipeline before building the code.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a version variable in pipeline, and then set conditions to increment the variable (variable auto increment once the changes are made to the particular branch), then use the variable in the subsequent tasks.

To do that, please install [Build Updating Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-BuildUpdating-Tasks) extension, and use the `Set variable on a build definition` task to update a variable in a Build Definition with conditions.

For example:

1. Create a variable in your pipeline (`count` here):

[image]

2. Then, add the `Set variable on a build definition` task in your pipeline:
   [image]

Set the conditions based on your scenario, in the following YAML sample we set a variable `isMain` and the value is `true` when the branch is `main`. Set the condition in `Set variable on a build definition` task, if the value is `true`, then the `count` variable will Autoincrement.

```
variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]

steps:

- task: BuildVariableTask@2
  displayName: Update the variable
  inputs:
    buildmode: 'Prime'
    variable: 'count'
    mode: 'Autoincrement'
    usePSCore: False
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, 'true'))
```

In the subsequent tasks you can use the "`count`" variable as the JAR version.